# Logstash Filter on Specific Values

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm relatively new to Logstash but have been successful up to this point. I'm parsing through a log and viewing the output in Kibana.

What I'd like to do is output only the data that I'm interested in. This includes data where the `source = linux` and the `number = 78 or 80`.

I'm trying to use the `drop{}` function to do this by trying to remove anything that does not meet these conditions. If the source is not equal to linux and the number is not 78 or 80, then drop it. Logic tells me this would only send what I want in the output but I'm not having any luck. It works great for one or the other (just filtering on the source or just on the numbers) but when I try to do both, it only takes the first condition. I've tried a few different ways: nested if statements, separate if statements, using !=, not in, etc.

Below is my code (notice the conditional in the filter):

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/user/logs/os_log.csv"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\,\"?%{NUMBER:number}\s*<%{NUMBER:carrotnumber}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslogtimestamp}\s*%{WORD:object}\s*%{USERNAME:source}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:event}" }
    }

    if [source] != "linux" and [number] not in ["78","80"] {
        drop {}
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like you meant:

```
if [source] != "linux" or [number] not in ["78","80"] {
    drop {}
}
```